# using "Perf stat" to profile both process and system-wide events simultaneously

Tags: linux, perf

as in title, is it possible to profile hardware events both per process and system-wide within the same perf stat execution?
To be more precise, the perf stat command would return two lists of perf events, one for the process initialised with perf stat, the second one for system-wide data.
I know a possible alternative would be to use --per-core and pin the process to one core, while being able to check what is happening on the other cores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system-wide option `-a` is an attribute of the perf command itself rather than an attribute of an event to be profiled, so you can't collect event counts per-process and system-wide using a single perf command.

However, you can run multiple perf processes simultaneously with overlapping events. For example, if you want to profile a specific process and the entire system, you can launch two `perf stat` commands, one for each purpose. Internally, the perf_event subsystem schedules all the enabled events on each core. If all specified events cannot be scheduled at the same time, either because there are conflicts between the constraints of some events or the number of hardware events is larger than the number of performance monitoring countering registers, multiplexing is used. Each event from each `perf stat` command requires a dedicated PMC.

On modern Intel processors, you can have 8 general-purpose PMCs per logical core instead of just 4 if you disable hyperthreading (or if HT is not supported by the processor model). This may help eliminate or reduce multiplexing.

Otherwise, I don't think there is an easy to go about this.

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive answer. Indeed, as you proposed I solved my problem by running multiple perf processes simultaneously, but would have strongly preferred a single command solution.